# What node to expand using A-star if the open list contains more than one node with the least cost value?

Tags: language-agnostic, artificial-intelligence, a-star

Using the A-star algorithm to perform a search, if you have two (or more) nodes in the open list with the same value, which happens to be the least cost value, what node should you choose?

I know you should choose the one with the least heuristic value, but what if this cost is also the same?

For example:

I have two nodes expanded from the root. f(n1) = f(n2) and h(n1) = h(n2).
Which node should I expand, n1 or n2?
Should I expand randomly or use the first one added to the open list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- A common strategy is to handle the tied nodes in a LIFO manner. This gives the algorithm a bit more depth-first character. In general this does not have to be most efficient solution.
- You can also use chance to break the ties.
- Or you choose the pragmatic strategy of picking the first node your algorithm produces in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Most algorithms I've seen or written just choose the first value that is found to have the lower cost.  If the next value compared has the exact same cost, the first would be chosen to expand.  The algorithm will generally look back and expand the other soon enough anyways so no harm.